# Running a Macro to hide rows in different sheet based on a cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a VBA macro to hide rows in a different sheet based on a cell value.

What I did was to record a macro and hide rows which I wanted, and edited the generated VBA code to include an IF condition. Below is the code which I am working on currently.

```
Sub OpenQuestionnaire()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("C. Questionnaire")
        .Visible=xlSheetVisible
        .Activate

        If Range("XFD3").Value="Offsite - Lite" Then
            Sheets("C. Questionnaire").Select
            Columns("G").Hidden=True
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=7
            Range("H166:I181,67:67,68:68,69:69,70:70").Select
            Range("A70").Activate
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=14
            Range("H166:I181,67:67,68:68,69:69,70:70,80:80,82:82").Select
            Range("A82").Activate
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=5
            Range("H166:I181,67:67,68:68,69:69,70:70,80:80,82:82,87:87,91:91").Select
            Range("A91").Activate
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=18
            Range("H166:I181,67:67,68:68,69:69,70:70,80:80,82:82,87:87,91:91,103:103").Select
            Range("A103").Activate
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
            Range("H166:I181,67:67,68:68,69:69,70:70,80:80,82:82,87:87,91:91,103:103,113:113,114:114").Select
            Range("A114").Activate 
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=7 
            Range("H166:I181,67:67,68:68,69:69,70:70,80:80,82:82,87:87,91:91,103:103,113:113,114:114,121:121").Select
            Range("A121").Activate
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=4 
            Range("H166:I181,67:67,68:68,69:69,70:70,80:80,82:82,87:87,91:91,103:103,113:113,114:114,121:121,124:124,127:127").Select
            Range("A127").Activate
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=5 
            Range("H166:I181,67:67,68:68,69:69,70:70,80:80,82:82,87:87,91:91,103:103,113:113,114:114,121:121,124:124,127:127,128:128,129:129,130:130,134:134").Select
            Range("A134").Activate
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=8
            Range("H166:I181,67:67,68:68,69:69,70:70,80:80,82:82,87:87,91:91,103:103,113:113,114:114,121:121,124:124,127:127,128:128,129:129,130:130,134:134,138:138").Select 
            Range("A138").Activate
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=8
            Range("H166:I181,67:67,68:68,69:69,70:70,80:80,82:82,87:87,91:91,103:103,113:113,114:114,121:121,124:124,127:127,128:128,129:129,130:130,134:134,138:138,146:146,147:147").Select
            Range("A147").Activate
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=2
            Range("H166:I181,67:67,68:68,69:69,70:70,80:80,82:82,87:87,91:91,103:103,113:113,114:114,121:121,124:124,127:127,128:128,129:129,130:130,134:134,138:138,146:146,147:147,152:152").Select
            Range("A152").Activate
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=25
            Range("H166:I181,67:67,68:68,69:69,70:70,80:80,82:82,87:87,91:91,103:103,113:113,114:114,121:121,124:124,127:127,128:128,129:129,130:130,134:134,138:138,146:146,147:147,152:152,172:172,173:173").Select
            Range("A173").Activate
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
            Range("H166:I181,67:67,68:68,69:69,70:70,80:80,82:82,87:87,91:91,103:103,113:113,114:114,121:121,124:124,127:127,128:128,129:129,130:130,134:134,138:138,146:146,147:147,152:152,172:172,173:173,176:176").Select
            Range("A176").Activate
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
            Range("H166:I181,67:67,68:68,69:69,70:70,80:80,82:82,87:87,91:91,103:103,113:113,114:114,121:121,124:124,127:127,128:128,129:129,130:130,134:134,138:138,146:146,147:147,152:152,172:172,173:173,176:176,185:185,187:187").Select
            Range("A187").Activate
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=7
            Range("H166:I181,67:67,68:68,69:69,70:70,80:80,82:82,87:87,91:91,103:103,113:113,114:114,121:121,124:124,127:127,128:128,129:129,130:130,134:134,138:138,146:146,147:147,152:152,172:172,173:173,176:176,185:185,187:187,191:191,192:192").Select
            Range("A192").Activate
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=1
Error here:>>> Union(Range("H166:I181,67:67,68:68,69:69,70:70,80:80,82:82,87:87,91:91,103:103,113:113,114:114,121:121,124:124,127:127,128:128,129:129,130:130,134:134,138:138,146:146,147:147,152:152,172:172,173:173,176:176,185:185,187:187,191:191,192:192,194:194,195:195")).Select
            Range("A195").Activate
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=4
            Union(Range("200:200,H166:I181,67:67,68:68,69:69,70:70,80:80,82:82,87:87,91:91,103:103,113:113,114:114,121:121,124:124,127:127,128:128,129:129,130:130,134:134,138:138,146:146,147:147,152:152,172:172,173:173,176:176,185:185,187:187,191:191,192:192,194:194"), Rows("195:195")).Select
            Range("A200").Activate
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=7
            Union(Range("200:200,208:208,211:211,H166:I181,67:67,68:68,69:69,70:70,80:80,82:82,87:87,91:91,103:103,113:113,114:114,121:121,124:124,127:127,128:128,129:129,130:130,134:134,138:138,146:146,147:147,152:152,172:172,173:173,176:176,185:185,187:187,191:191"), Range("192:192,194:194,195:195")).Select
            Range("A211").Activate
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=20
            Union(Range("200:200,208:208,211:211,228:228,229:229,231:231,232:232,H166:I181,67:67,68:68,69:69,70:70,80:80,82:82,87:87,91:91,103:103,113:113,114:114,121:121,124:124,127:127,128:128,129:129,130:130,134:134,138:138,146:146,147:147,152:152,172:172,173:173"), Range("176:176,185:185,187:187,191:191,192:192,194:194,195:195")).Select
            Range("A232").Activate
            Selection.EntireRow.Hidden=True
        ElseIf Range("XFD3").Value="Onsite - Full" Then
            Columns("G").Hidden=True
        End If

        If Range("XFD1").Value="No" Then 
            Range("H166").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1="Not Applicable"
            Range("I166").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1="Not Applicable"
            Range("H166").Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H166:H181"), Type:=xlFillDefault
            Range("H166:H181").Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H166:I181"), Type:=xlFillDefault
            Range("H166:I181").Select
            Rows("163:181").EntireRow.Hidden=True
        ElseIf Range("XFD1").Value="Yes" Then 
            Rows("163:181").EntireRow.Hidden=False
        End If

        If Range("XFD2").Value="No" Then 
            Range("H216").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1="Not Applicable"
            Range("I216").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1="Not Applicable"
            Range("H216").Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H216:H232"), Type:=xlFillDefault
            Range("H216:H232").Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H216:I232"), Type:=xlFillDefault
            Range("H216:I232").Select
            Rows("213:233").EntireRow.Hidden=True
        ElseIf Range("XFD2").Value="Yes" Then
            Rows("213:233").EntireRow.Hidden=False
        End If 

    End With
End Sub
```

I receive an `Argument Not Optional` error. Let me know where I going wrong. I have highlighted the line where I am getting this error.

Comment: I was not able to indent the  code. Need some urgent assistance in this code.

Comment: You don't indicate where the error is, and we surely don't need all that code?  If you have it indented in excel then copy-paste into your question should keep the indenting.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to simply put an IF statement in the code you have.  Depending on how complicated your criteria for hiding rows is, you could filter the data which hides the rows automatically. Even with a complicated criteria you can add a column with a formula that returns "1" or "Hide" if the row meets your criteria and then filter that column to hide the rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use a macro then it should be pretty short.

```
' get the number of rows by looking at column A (only works if you have no gaps in column A
intLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' loop through all rows
For intRow = 1 To intLastRow
    ' test if the current row matches your criteria. Put your own IF condition here
    ' cells(row number, column number) 1=A, 2=B, 3=C .....
    If Cells(intRow, 2) = "yes" And Cells(intRow, 3) = "no" Then
        'hide the current row if it matches the criteria
        Cells(intRow, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next
```